# Нет подключения к SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Не могу понять в чем причина. На моей машине подключение к серверу происходит на ура. Через косую указываю имя сервера и экземпляра. На рабочем сервере не подключается. Подскажите, может нужно как-то дополнительно настроить sql server?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection/(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                                                    Initial atalog=test;
                                                    Integrated Security=SSPI;
                                                    User ID=sa;
                                                    Password=pass");
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();

    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Connection Open");
    }
    catch {
        System.Console.WriteLine("");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Не удалось получить данные");                
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы подключаетесь к разным базам (локальной, на каждом из компов), это так и требуется?

Comment: Да, я в коде указываю персональное подключение. Пользователь ничего не вводит, просто запускает ехе при необходимости.

Comment: я меняю название: сервера, базы, пароль и на другом сервере отрабатывает исключение.

Comment: В примере еще опечатка `Initial Catalog` вместо `Initial atalog=test`

Comment: да это я случайно букву удалил когда создавал запрос. Скрипт отрабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так заполнив имя сервера и имя БД:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string _имяСервераБД = "";
    string _имяБД = "";
    string _имяПользБД = "sa";
    string _парольПользБД = "pass";

    String строкаСоединения = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3};Connect Timeout=10", _имяСервераБД, _имяБД, _имяПользБД, _парольПользБД);

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(строкаСоединения))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1", myConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Open");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Не удалось получить данные. Причина: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }   
    }      
}
```

Comment: Можно даже в круглых скобках прямо писать переменные

Comment: нет, не помогло

Comment: 25-я ошибка, не валидная строка подключения. Данные указываю верно. К моем ПК тоже работает

Comment: какой порт юзает это подключение знает кто?